# Jmeter : Transfer a file from server (using ssh sftp) to sftp

Tags: jmeter, sftp

I need to send file from remote server (**/root/novalnew/**) to same remote server with other folder (**/root/novalold/**) and trying it by using SSH SFTP using JMETER

**with configuration
Action : Get
Source Path : /root/novalnew/Ping-Telnet-Proxy 1.txt
Print file content : False
Destination Path : /root/novalold**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Ash.png)

and i've got the error **SftpException**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMdPm.png)

Any help would greatly appreciated.

I need to send file from remote server to same remote server with other folder

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "send"? If you want to [assess the file download and upload speed](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing) you need to:

1. Store the file in your local folder by supplying the correct and valid path using `get` action

   [image]
2. And then upload the file to the new location using `put` action:

   [image]

If you just need to copy or move the file - go for [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command)

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri, yes, i just need to copy file (Ping-Telnet-Proxy 1.txt) in folder /root/novalnew to folder /root/novalold, i already use  SSH Command but still getting error
        
Response code:1
Response message:OK


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: null

Maybe any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, just lacking this (") after (/root/novalold) (/bin/bash -c "cp \"/root/novalnew/Ping-Telnet-Proxy 1.txt\" /root/novalold"), it's worked, thanks for your help and support Mr. Dmitri.